# VB2010 export SQL dataset to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, excel

As a very newbie to any form of coding following a long break, I have started a little project at work for which i'd appreciate a bit of help.

I bit of background - When items are submitted to our office they're input into a bespoke software which stores them in a MS SQL 2012 DB. This cannot be changed. We also use a local spreadsheet to keep track of who is working on what item and this spreadsheet is currently populated manually...

I've made a start on an automated script, as you can see below, but i've no real idea whether i'm on the right track. So far i've used the debug.print function to confirm the connection is sound, but when I run this code, it returns a COM exception on line

```
xlSht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
```

Can anyone show me the errors of my ways?

Thanks

```vb
    'Create connection
    Dim connectionstring As String
    connectionstring = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Database=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=true;"

    Try
        SQLConn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        SQLConn.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " Error Connecting to database!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'run SQL query to Dataset
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from person.addresstype", SQLConn)

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim filename = "C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\testing.xlsx"
    Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSht

    da.Fill(ds)

    'copy data from Dataset to xlsx
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlBook = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(filename)
    xlSht = xlApp.activesheet

    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            xlSht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
        Next
    Next

    xlBook.Save()
    xlApp.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    xlSht = Nothing
    xlBook = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `.ToString` to the end otherwise you are passing an Object

Comment: Note: You are always better to use the Typesafe `.Field(Of T)` function get the data from a datarow - rather than the `.Item` property

Comment: Matt - thanks for the swift reply. Adding .ToString prevents the error. I can't take any credit for the dataset part of the above code - i've been stealing bits from all over the place trying to get this to work. As i said - very newbie!. Could you offer (or direct me towards) a prefered xlsht.cells input code line? Thanks. Richard

Comment: 'xlSht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j).ToString' has done the job... Now just to get the darn spreadsheet to save/close!!. Thanks